# Normalize.css from blueprint overwrite styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, blueprint

I implement popOver from blueprint in my react app (https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#blueprint/getting-started) and when i set it up the normalize.css overwrite my styles..if I remove this the popOver stop working.

How can i fix it?
The imports are in my index.jsx and html

Thanksss!!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <!--
    manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
    homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
  -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fav.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/load.css">

  <link href="path/to/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="path/to/node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="path/to/node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/App/App';
import("normalize.css");  
import("@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css"); 
import("@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css"); 

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: (1) You could try to include the normalize.css after the other css.
(2) In your own css you might have to further specify the selectors that get overwriten
(3) You could try to only include the css of normalize.css that you really need.

Comment: @Jeremy I try your options and still don ' t work.. and the popover needs the 3 css.